# Using Koala Facebook API to get information from app pages

Tags: facebook, koala, koala-gem

How do I use the koala gem to get information from an app page?
For example, if I want to get information about candy crush saga's liked pages, I type @graph.get_object(candycrushsaga+"/likes").

How can I get other features such as comments, likes, and shares?
Is this possible using koala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use *feed* node using *get_connections*, i.e.

```
@graph.get_connections('candycrushsaga','feed?fields=status_type,type,story,message,likes{name},comments,link,name, from')
```

More info https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post#fields.